# Cleaning up a messy VBA formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to Excel VBA (started about a day ago!) but I'm slowly struggling through. I've created a formula that copies a selection of three cells to another part of the sheet if column D contains the value "(2)", then assigns the value "0" to some more cells in the same row.

The trouble is, I've used a mixture of recording and typing my macro so the end result is pretty messy. Currently the macro takes a while to complete (it moves everything around and then a little hourglass appears for a good 15 seconds or so). I'm assuming this is in part due to my use of "Select" (I'm aware this is a bad thing!) but I'm just trying to work out what I can strip from the formula to make it more efficient while retaining the same outcome.

```
Sub MoveNames()    

    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

    Set SrchRng = Range("D:D")

    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "(2)") > 0 Then
         cel.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:C1").Select
          Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 40).Range("A1").Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4) = "0"
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5) = "0"
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6) = "0"
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7) = "0"
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10) = "0"
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, -12) = "0"
            End If
             Next cel

        End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you. All of these worked well. I'll remember to put any questions for working code in "Code Review" from now on.

Comment: Definitely send it to CR, we have an active, experienced VBA community that would love to help you out.

Comment: Just as an aside, the easiest way to **massively** speed up execution speed is to put `Application.ScreenUpdating = False Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start of your code, and then setting them back to `True` at the end of your code.

Comment: Thanks Zak, extremely helpful to know!

Comment: @Zak bear in mind however, that you should always use appropriate error handling to turn these options back on in the event of an unexpected error .

Comment: @MacroMan Sure, but then I'd be getting into Code Review territory, in a comment, so I thought I'd keep it (relatively) brief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Sub MoveNames()
    Dim SrchRng As Range
    lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SrchRng = Range("D1:D" & lastrow)
    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "(2)") > 0 Then
            With cel.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:C1")
                .Copy cel.Offset(-1, 40).Range("A1")
            End With
            With cel.Offset(-1, 40)
            .Offset(0, -4) = "0"
                .Offset(0, -5) = "0"
                .Offset(0, -6) = "0"
                .Offset(0, -7) = "0"
                .Offset(0, -10) = "0"
                .Offset(0, -12) = "0"
            End With
          End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to do, this should do the same thing without having to use any objects or any copy/paste methods:

```
Sub MM_MoveNames()

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        If InStr(Cells(i, 4).value, "(2)") Then
            Cells(i - 1, 44).Resize(1, 3).value = Cells(i, 5).Resize(1, 3).value
            Cells(i, 37).Resize(1, 4).value = 0
            Cells(i, 34).value = 0
            Cells(i, 32).value = 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

More importantly though - if your code is working, and you just want advice for improvements then you should post your code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), not on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot, you can definitely clean it up more by combining the multiple offsets and ranges.

```
Sub test()

    Dim rngIndex As Range

    For Each rngIndex In Range("D:D")
        If InStr(1, rngIndex.Value, "(2)") > 0 Then

            rngIndex.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:C1").Copy _
                rngIndex.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:C1").Offset(-1, 40).Range("A1")

            With rngIndex.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:C1")
                Range(.Offset(0, -4), .Offset(0, -7)).Value = 0
                .Offset(0, -10) = "0"
                .Offset(0, -12) = "0"
            End With
        End If
    Next rngIndex

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going throug each cell in column `D`, you can go through just the used range, like this:

```
Set SrchRng = Range("D1:D" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
```

Which should speed it up quite a bit.

You can use `Select`, I found that easier when I was learning VBA myself. In time you will learn to avoid it. 
To speed up macro execution when using `Select`, you can add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of your procedure.
Disabling automatic calculations is also beneficial, you can do it by adding `Application.Calculation = xlManual` and `Application.Calculation = xlManual` at the beginning and end respectively.

Hope that helps. if you have more questions, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

My turn - instead of looking at each cell, just jump to the ones containing **(2)**.

```
Sub MoveNames()

    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String

    Set SrchRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")

    Set rFound = SrchRng.Find("(2)", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirstAddress = rFound.Address
        Do
            rFound.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 3).Copy Destination:=rFound.Offset(-1, 41)
            rFound.Offset(-1, 34).Resize(, 4) = 0
            rFound.Offset(-1, 29) = 0
            rFound.Offset(-1, 31) = 0
            Set rFound = SrchRng.FindNext(rFound)
        Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> sFirstAddress
    End If

End Sub
```